# Distance between a point and a subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, inequality, metric-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ be two nonempty closed subsets of a metric space $(X,d)$, $A\cap B = \emptyset$, and the distance from a point to a subset defined by:

$$d(x,A) = \inf d(x,a) \quad\forall \,a \in A$$

I need to prove that

$$d(x,A) + d(x,B) > 0 \quad\forall\, x \in X$$

and if we define

$$f(x) = \frac{d(x,A)}{d(x,A) + d(x,B)}$$

then prove that

$$f(X) \subset [0,1], \, f(A)=\{0\} \quad \&\quad f(B)=\{1\}.$$

I've already proved that $d(x,A)$ is a distance, so I know $d(x,A) \ge 0$

So the idea I have was that if

$$x\in A, \quad d(x,A)=0 \quad\&\quad d(x,B) > 0 \\ x\in B, \quad d(x,B) = 0 \quad \&\quad d(x,A) >0$$ since $$A\cap B = \emptyset$$

But I don't know if that's all I need to say to finish the prove for the first proposition.

For the second one I know that $$f(x)=d(x,A) $$ is continuous and if the first proposition is true then $$f(x)=\frac{d(x,A)}{d(x,A)+d(x,B)}$$ is continuous too.

So it's obvious for me that $$0\le f\le 1$$ but I don't know if I just can say that with this ideas $$f(X) \subset [0,1]$$

Because I want to write a complete proof

Comment: What does it mean that $d(x,A)=0$ for a point $x$?

Comment: What is $f$ and what are you supposed to prove?

Comment: It also is true that f is continuous Hence closed sets in a metric space are $G_{\delta}$ sets and are functionally closed.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have that f(x) is bounded by 0 and 1, f(X) = [0,1].

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I just edited my question